Qual o significado e classe gramatical de "nenhum" em "Eu jogo futebol mas não sou nenhum Pelé."
Procurei no Priberam mas não encontrei nenhum uso semelhante.
Frases exemplo, seriam:

Jogo regularmente, nível intermediário, mas não sou nenhum Kasparov.
Ela é bonitinha, mas naõ é nenhuma Miss Universo.
Eu sei que não sou nenhum galã.


Na frase

Ele pode ser o campeão brasileiro, mas não é um Kasparov.

é feita uma comparação entre os dois jogadores:

Ele pode ser o campeão brasileiro, mas não é um [jogador tão bom quanto] Kasparov.

Usar o pronome indefinido "nenhum" ao invés de "um" enfatiza a negativa, como coloca o Aulete:

como reforço de uma negação: Não era nenhuma tola para acreditar nisso.


Isso também acontece no inglês com no (sign. nehnum): "He is as good basketball player, but he's no Michael Jordan" >> "Ele é um jogador de basquete, mas não é nenhum Michael Jordan".

@Schilive, verdade, a expressão existe no inglês também, mas acho que falta a dupla negativa do "não... nenhum...", embora talvez coloquialmente se possa falar algo como "he ain't no Michael Jordan".
